# Cannot add/edit Mail Merge to Custom form with Ribbon Workbench

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013, crm-ribbon-workbench

My clients need to have the Mail Merge option in the Sales/Invoice tab. I'm trying to add the Mail Merge button to my Invoice Entity in CRM 2013, using Ribbon Workbench. It looks pretty simple when I read the materials for it. Here's a simple tutorial about that:

http://www.blog.affiliatedcrm.com/adding-the-mail-merge-button-in-dynamics-crm-2013

The thing is that I follow all of the above steps (not only in this particular tutorial. I tried 4-5 other sources as well), but as you can see in the picture below, the button and the function for it appears in the Ribbon Workbench, but not in the actual form.

Here you can see that the button is created in the ribbon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYf7A.jpg

But it is not on the Invoice tab. I'll post the picture in a comment bellow, because I dont' have enough rating to post more than 2 links.

I noticed that if I create just a button / without a function attached to it / the button appears in the Invoice form, but the moment I put a command to go with it, the button itself disappears.

Please, help me get this Mail Merge function working.

Comment: Here is what is on the Invoice Panel in CRM:

http://i.imgur.com/J97UG3D.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the button isn't showing is that it has a Display Rule that hides it if Mail Merge is not enabled on the entity. Invoices do not support mail merging so it will not show.
Scott

Comment: Thanks Scott, I'm so glad to hear from you. I figured out that it is not going to work this way, so I followed one of your answers in the MSCRM Community (This one : https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/116656.aspx) and it's an awesome workaround. But can you make a list of the steps that need to be done, in order to complete the task correctly. 

Thanks in Advance Scott.